# CoreTelephony running on background iphone sdk

Tags: ios, background, core-telephony

Is possible to run CoreTelephony framework in background mode? i'm making hardware for iphone ad i need when the iphone is in sleep mode and when you recived a call or sms my hardware make sound. i can make this when my app is running but when i put the iphone on sleep mode not work.
Is possible to do these work in background ?
thanks !

Answer (score 0):

yes its possible....whichever function or method it is you want to run background, just call the function in application did enter background method in  your `appdelegate.m` file